# Getting Key Press Information in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a Python program that reads input from the command line like the input builtin function. I would also like to be able to detect key presses of certain keys (such as the home, end, page up, page down, function keys, etc.) When one of those keys is pressed I would like to fire off an event (i.e. call a mapped function). Other keys should go into a buffer to be returned when enter is pressed (i.e. act like the input built in). Finally I would like this to be cross platform and run on the command line.

Effectively I would like to be able to scroll a table down a page when the page down key is entered and still return the text from the input line when enter is hit.

I have found any number of solutions that don't fit all of these criteria:

- input builtin - doesn't detect special keys and doesn't return until enter entered
- curses - not shipped with Windows
- msvcrt.getch - Windows only
- tkinter - doesn't run on command line
- readline - can't remap the standard navigation keys (such as home and end). When I bind these keys it still performs the vi or emacs navigation function

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the keyboard module in python

```
pip3 install keyboard
```

You can then code as

```
import keyboard #Using module keyboard
while True:  #making a loop
    try: #used try so that if user pressed other than the given key error will not be shown
        if keyboard.is_pressed('a'): #if key 'a' is pressed 
            print('You Pressed A Key!')
            break #finishing the loop
        else:
            pass
    except:
        break #if user pressed other than the given key the loop will 
    break
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Is there a way to prevent the keyboard module from reading the keyboard from any window and just look at the window the Python program is running in?